# ArcPy empty shape?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing

I have a small script to search through a featureclass and copy and entire row to another featureclass.  Its working well, in that I get all of the attributes for the row, but there is no geometry for the layer and no shapes appear.  It is a POLYLINE layer and all of my shape_lengths = 0

```
    import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


env.workspace = r"C:\temp\gamma\Gamma_Survey_With_Lines.gdb"


Detector_Line = env.workspace + "/Detector_Line"
GammaDetectionLocation = env.workspace + "/GammaDetectionLocation"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(GammaDetectionLocation, "GammaDetectionLocation1") 


#lyr2Explode = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "CopyOfGammaDetectionLocation", "POLYLINE",GammaDetectionLocation,"DISABLED","DISABLED",GammaDetectionLocation)
lyr2Explode = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env.workspace, "CopyofDetectorLine", "POLYLINE",Detector_Line,"DISABLED","DISABLED",Detector_Line)


cur = arcpy.InsertCursor(lyr2Explode)

field = "GlobalID"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Detector_Line)
for row in cursor:
    #print(row.getValue(field))
    globalid = row.getValue(field)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("GammaDetectionLocation1", "NEW_SELECTION", "SourceTrack = '" + globalid + "'")
    count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("GammaDetectionLocation1").getOutput(0))
    if(count == 0):
        print count
        feat = cur.newRow()
        feat.shape = row.Shape
        feat.setValue("UserID","doodie")
        cur.insertRow(feat)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fields are identical between the two layers. I'd try listing all fields and adding the `"SHAPE@"` token to make sure you snag the geometry.

Maybe something like this:

```
#Fields list
#Get all fields
flds = [f.name for f in ListFields (Detector_Line)]
#Add shape@ token
flds += ["SHAPE@"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Detector_Line, flds) as sCur:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(lyr2Explode, flds) as iCur:
        for row in sCur:
            print(row[17])
            globalid = row[17]
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("GammaDetectionLocation1", "NEW_SELECTION", "SourceTrack = '" + globalid + "'")
            count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("GammaDetectionLocation1").getOutput(0))
            if(count == 0):
                print count
                iCur.insertRow(row)
```

if there's trouble with the OID field you can modify it as such:

```
oidFld = arcpy.Describe (Detector_Line).OIDFieldName
flds = [f.name for f in ListFields (Detector_Line) if f.name != oidFld]
...
```

Comment: The shape field was there, not sure what the issue is.  I have reworked the code, updated above, to apply the row.Shape, but now I must set each attribute individually.  Not a bad thing, but a bit more tedious.  You would think "*" would bring over everything, but the geometry is empty still.

Comment: Did you give my method a shot? The `SHAPE@` token is different from the shape field name. See data access search cursor help.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did, it made no difference.